# Mongodb SyntaxError: Unexpected token }

Tags: mongodb-query

This is my query

```
db.courses.find({"courses"})
```

on my courses collection. I'm not sure what's going wrong in my syntax considering I have two brackets.

The error says

```
E QUERY    SyntaxError: Unexpected token }
```

Comment: that is not a valid mongodb query

Answer (score 1):

You need to past a valid JSON object to the `find()` method 
`{courses:'xxx'}`

If you are trying to get all, then you just need to paste a empty braces, `db.courses.find({})` or leave it blank.

Read a little more about MongoDB and the find method [in the documentation](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/method/db.collection.find/).

Comment: I am trying to find a course based on my course json object. If I just have the course number 12712 and the lecture: A, then how can I find that course in a json object (the first object in the courses object) filled with many of these courses? My attempt at this is

    db.courses.find({"courses.12712"})

but I am getting an error. JSON Snippet in comment below

Comment: SNIPPET OF JSON OBJECT:

{ "_id" : ObjectId("566f824641b9b2eba94a9ff4"), "courses" : { "12712" : { "department" : "Civil & Environmental Engineering", "lectures" : [ { "instructors" : [ "Vanbriesen" ], "sections" : [ ], "lecture" : "A", "meetings" : [ { "room" : "DH 2302", "location" : "Pittsburgh, Pennsylvania", "end" : "04:20PM", "days" : "MW", "begin" : "03:00PM" } ] } ], "name" : "Introduction to Sustainable Engineering", "units" : 12, "prereqs" : "", "semester" : [ "F" ], "coreqs" : "", "desc" : "This course begins with an overview...." }}

Comment: As a say you need to pass a valid json document, {"courses.12712"} is not a valid json document i guess that you are trying to get the courses that have the property "12712" you can do this `db.courses.find({"courses.12712": { $exists: true }})`